# is it possible to list of libraries used in a app from iTunes

Tags: ios, shared-libraries, itunes, reverse-engineering

Is there any workaround or way to get the list of libraries used by an app which is already published on iTunes ?

Considering app is free to download from iTunes and after downloading some-way to get libraries used by the app.

Thanks

Comment: most big apps have an "About" page in the app which lists the 3rd party license stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reason, Apple won't allow you to break into the app.

Also, there seems no way to decompile the ios ipa for now (See reference below)

https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4096/decompiling-iphone-app

https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-decompile-iOS-apps-like-Android-apps